# Chrome Extension - Don't load certain parts of a webpage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

A recurring problem with modern web design can be summed up as "too much sh** all over the place". There're two problems with this: one, it takes up memory and takes longer to load, and two, it visually clutters the webpage.

If I just wanted to solve the second problem, I wouldn't need help. JavaScript can delete DOM nodes and CSS can hide them, so there're already a few visible ways to simply hide parts of a webpage. What I want to do is solve the first problem - make a webpage load faster by not loading certain elements.

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to selectively download certain parts of an HTML file. But once the source is downloaded, the browser doesn't have to actually parse and display all of it, does it?

Of course, if this is done after it's already been parsed and displayed, it would be pointless. So I need a way to tell Chrome what to do *before it begins parsing the HTML*. Is this possible, and do you think it would significantly reduce load time/memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately Ive never seen a way of changing the html before Chrome renders it.
But as far as blocking things that that page gets to display then Id recommend just using AdBlock https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom
AdBlock can be used to stop resources (js,images,css,xmlhttprequest) from ever being downloaded (it blocks them in the background using the webRequest api) and can also hide elements using css...its rather effective (just remember to select advanced options in its option page and then when you click the AdBlock button you get "Show the resource list").  Also installing Flashblock can help...or disable plugins in Chromes settings, doing this will make them not load but will still show on the page and then you can make them load.

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible! Meet the newest Chrome API: webRequest, finalized in the current version of Chrome - 17.

Docs for webRequest: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest

I'm trying to think of a solid way to do this... one suggestion I have is using the 'sub_frame' filter, and watching if it's a like/tweet/social button url

You could also block known analytics stuff... and the list goes on! Have fun! Do you have an email list I can sub to for when you launch? If not, get one and drop me a comment!

(From the comments, here is how a innerHTML hack could work)

```
//This modLoop constantly peers into and modifies the innerHTML in attempt to modify the html before it's fully processed.
var modLoop = function modLoop(){
  var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML
  //modify the page html before it's processed!
  //like: html = html.replace('//google'sCDN.com/jquery/1.7.1/', chrome.extension.getURL('localjQuery.1.7.1.js'));
  //I just pulled that ^ out of nowhere, you'll want to put careful thought into it.
  //Then, mod the innerHTML:
  document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
  setTimeout(modLoop, 1);
};
var starter = function starter(){
  if (document.documentElement.innerHTML && document.documentElement.innerHTML.lengh > 0) {
    modLoop();
  } else {
    setTimeout(starter, 1);
  }
};
starter();
```

Comment: more on webRequest, you can use onBeforeRequest in a blocking fashion and cancel requests whole heartedly

Comment: woah woah, I'm flattered, but I'm not even a professional coder. You probably don't want to use any extension I, er, "launch". And that's assuming I ever finish this, I mean it's essentially a hobby project.

Comment: But anyway, are you sure this is pertinent? This looks like it's for blocking entire requests, I need a way to modify how the response is parsed -- skip parsing on certain tag types, etc.

Comment: This is a crazy hack you could try, but I remember fudging with the DOM and finding that .innerHTML is available before the actual DOM nodes that HTML represents. For formatting, I'm going to add this to my answer

Comment: ...do you want to skip parsing <script> tags? You can load the page via an ajax GET and then insert the response html as the innerHTML for the whole page (document.documentElement.innerHTML). You can also start raising money so you can download the whole web like Google, but just serve optimized versions (opera does this... don't think they have an API :(

Comment: entire request blocking in definitely pertinent - the main slowdown on a page is downloading the page. You can also try playing with the `window.stop();` method in javascript.